# Customize UISearchBar: Trying to get rid of the 1px black line underneath the search bar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisearchbar

My question is already specified in the title: I would like to get rid of the black line drawn on the bottom of the `UISearchBar`. Any ideas?

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image: search bar with black bottom line]

**UPDATE**:

I think that the line is part of the `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView`. I still don't know how to remove it.

Comment: use this code to remove the 1px border: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64535982/2692839

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a `subview` to the `searchBar`'s view stack like so:

```
CGRect rect = self.searchBar.frame;
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height-2,rect.size.width, 2)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.searchBar addSubview:lineView];
```

Here, `self.searchBar` is an `UISearchBar` pointer of my controller class.

Comment: I added the line in the layoutSubviews method of a UISearchBar's subclass. I was working with a subclass anyway.

Answer (score 76):

Try this

```
 searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;

 searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: Works for me, in my case I am using a custom bar tint color so my code is as follows (swift):
`searchBar.layer.borderColor = searchBar.barTintColor?.CGColor`

Comment: What helped me see why it works was to mistakenly set "searchBar.layer.borderColor = searchBar.tintColor?.CGColor"

Comment: So one says to add `searchBar.layer.borderColor = searchBar.barTintColor?.CGColor` and one to remove that -_-

Answer (score 53):

### Why:

So, I've dug into the API's trying to figure out why this is happening. Apparently whomever wrote the `UISearchBar` API is rasterizing the lines onto an image and setting it as it's `backgroundImage`.

### Solution:

I propose a simpler solution, if you want to set the `backgroundColor` and get rid of the hairlines:

```
searchBar.backgroundColor = <#... some color #>
searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage new];
```

Or if you just need a background image without the hairlines:

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = <#... some image #>
```

Comment: For iOS7+ you'll want to use the setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics: method instead.

Comment: This solution removes the bar.  Thanks @Oxcug!

Answer (score 48):

I have `0.5px` black horizontal lines both on top and on the bottom of my `UISearchBar`. The only way I had so far to get rid of them is by setting its style to `Minimal`:

```
mySearchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
```

Comment: This makes textfield greyed inside serachbar

Answer (score 34):

Solution for

### XCode 10.1 Swift 4.2

[image]

Comment: Awesome, You made my day.

Comment: programmatically
'searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal'

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2:**

```
controller.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
controller.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 253/255, blue: 247/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

Answer based on Ayush's answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is ridiculous to have to go through hoops and bounds for this little 1 px line. I've been googling around for a couple of hours to get rid of it. I tried combos of different answer to get it to work. When I came back here I realized [Oxcug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275021/4833705) already had it but it's in Objective-C and that's not native for me.

Anyway here is the answer in **Swift 5**. If you want to have a color background inside the actual search textField I added that too.

```
// these 2 lines get rid of the 1 px line
searchBar.backgroundColor = .white
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()

// this line will let you color the searchBar textField where the user actually types
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set the tableHeaderView to `nil` before putting your `UISearchBar` there.

If that does not help, try to cover it up. First add your search bar to a generic and appropriately sized `UIView` (say, "wrapper") as a subview, then

```
CGRect frame = wrapper.frame;
CGRect lineFrame = CGRectMake(0,frame.size.height-1,frame.size.width, 1);
UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:lineFrame];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // or whatever your background is
[wrapper addSubView:line];
[line release];
```

And then add it to the tableHeaderView.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = wrapper;
[wrapper release];
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. Unluckily both solutions don't cover the line. Maybe is it a drop shadow on top of the table view? Strange!

Comment: "Set the `tableHeaderView` to `nil` before putting your `UISearchBar` there..."  Why does this work?

Answer (score 3):

This question has already been solved but maybe my solution can help someone else. I had a similar problem, except I was trying to remove the 1px top border.

If you subclass `UISearchBar` you can override the frame like this.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.y = -1.0f;
    [super setFrame:frame];

    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, 1.0f);
}
```

Or if you would like to fix the bottom pixel you could do something like this, (untested).

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.y = 1.0f;
    [super setFrame:frame];

    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -1.0f);
}
```

Only for simplicity of the example are the `clipsToBounds` and `searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment` in the `setFrame`.

Also the `searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment` is only needed to re-center the search field.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the `tableView` will shift 1px from updating the `origin.y` while the searchBar is active. It feels a little strange. I realized that the solution is as simple as setting, `self.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Answer (score 3):

I used

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage() // Removes the line
```

And it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Warning.  This is a hack.  Would like to know a better, more official way.

You can use the pony debugger to figure out where in the subview hierarchy it is.  I think the thing you are see is a private UIImageView called "separator"

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  for (UIView* view in self.searchBar.subviews)  {
    if (view.frame.size.height == 1 && [view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
      view.alpha = 0;
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
  [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

on iOS 5+ to get rid of the line.

Comment: This hides the search text input field instead of the bar's bottom line.

Answer (score -1):

what **worked with me** is, setting the searchbar `barTintColor` as the navbar color

```
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString(hexStr: "479F46")
```

after testing, it solves the problem in both iOS 10.x and 11.x

GIF :

[image]