# How to remove the extra black line beneath UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uisearchbar

After setting the tint of a `UISearchBar` to White:

[image]

There is an extra black line between the search box and the table:

[image]

How can I remove the black line?

Comment: have you cleared search bar's background ?

Comment: `searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize UISearchBar: Trying to get rid of the 1px black line underneath the search bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620564/customize-uisearchbar-trying-to-get-rid-of-the-1px-black-line-underneath-the-se)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just a tweak...

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: It didn't work, it didn't remove line separator, it just changes the search bar border colour.

Answer (score 0):

I realize Legolas answer is old - but I stumbled upon the same problem, and now it seems there instead of a borderColor is a special view acting as a shadow which creates this effect.

The only way of fixing this is to search for a view called "_UISearchBarShadowView" and hide it.

It is a subview of a subview of searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView and only exists after typing a character into the search bar. I fixed the problem with the code below.

(getSubviewByClass is a category of UIView I created to loop through views and find subviews by a string)

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    [self performSelector:@selector(searchResultsTableShouldChange) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0001];

}

- (void)searchResultsTableShouldChange {

    [[self.view getSubviewByClass:@"_UISearchBarShadowView"] setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing like getSubviewByClass: method on UIView base class.

Comment: That's why I wrote about it in parentheses above the example code. It's a category I created to make it easier to do recursive searches in UIViews.

Comment: Isn't this a "solution" if you want to get your app rejected?

Answer (score 0):

searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage new];

See the explanation from 'theMonster' here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275021/1751266