# Line Above UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

For quite some time, I had been trying to no avail to remove a pernicious line above my UISearchBar. It appears dark on a light background or light on a dark background:

[image] [image]

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228010/get-rid-of-line-above-uitableview), but it had nothing to do with the separator or pull-to-refresh. When I finally decided to give up and ask for help, I started poking around again and found a blindingly simple (though perhaps not entirely intuitive) solution, so I thought I'd share it in case others are facing the same issue. I configure the search bar as follows:

```
// I tried this drawing method
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"linen_bg_bar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]];
// and this one.
[self.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"linen_bg_bar.png"]]];
// Same problem either way.

[self.searchBar setPlaceholder:NSLocalizedString(@"Filter", @"placeholder text in the search bar")];
[self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"linen_textfield_search.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 16, 16, 16)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"linen_icon_search.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
self.table.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
[self.table setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"linen_bg_dark.png"]]];
```

Per [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229991/970132) suggestion, I tried drawing on top of it, but it seemed the drawing *still* got rendered below the line.

```
CGRect rect = self.searchBar.frame;
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, 2)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

See the example with my red "cover-up" line:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not **sure** this will work, but it makes sense, based on having to set a *negative* y value for the cover-up view.

```
searchBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! But it still seems strange to me that the search bar is drawing a line *outside* its bounds.

Comment: @enjayem I know. Are you specifically turning `clipsToBounds` off somewhere?

Comment: Nope. All I'm doing is setting custom background images.

Comment: man, this answer needs to be included in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620564/customize-uisearchbar-trying-to-get-rid-of-the-1px-black-line-underneath-the-se and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676320/how-to-remove-the-extra-black-line-beneath-uisearchbar

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:

```
self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = Color.CGColor;
self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

you can find searchBar property in your searchController

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was creating a `UISearchBar` in code and placing it in the nav bar as the right bar button item. Setting the background image to an empty image removed the 1 pixel line.

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that all I had to do was adjust the frame of the cover-up line to start 1pt *above* the search bar and I got a pretty 1pt gray line on top of my search bar.

```
CGRect rect = self.searchBar.frame;
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -1, rect.size.width, 1)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"353535" alpha:1.0];
[self.searchBar addSubview:lineView];
```

Voila.

Comment: I'm definitely open to other solutions. It's just the best I've been able to come up with.

Comment: I'm not saying I can do it any better. I'm just saying this solution seems a little hacky.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. I don't disagree with that at all. I'm hoping someone has a better solution.

Comment: I think I've found it. See answer!