# UISearchBar weird bar line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am working on UISearchBar which I have created programmatically. Below is what I am having an issue with:

[image: http://oi46.tinypic.com/2lo25qu.jpg]

How can I get rid of that line on this search bar?

The code is as following:

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
[self setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self setShowsCancelButton:NO];
```

Comment: please show us some relevant code to help you out .

Comment: This has been asked and solved here:[Customize UISearchBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620564/customize-uisearchbar-trying-to-get-rid-of-1px-black-line-underneath-the-search?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the background color as clearColor. You can remove the background view of `UISearchBar` instead :

```
for(UIView *view in [searchBar subviews]){
    if([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

// in the above code in place of "searchBar" you have to use "self"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

on iOS 5+ to get rid of the line.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was change the backing layer:

```
self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```